# How to make SLAM with other programs and tools?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone

I'd like to know a way to make Simultaneous Localization And Mapping (SLAM). All projects I've seen are driven by teleop_twist_key node, or a joystick. In order to apply SLAM, the wheeled robot I'm looking for needs to make autonomously a mapping for the planar environment it moves, preferably indoors. I know teleop node, navigation stack and gmapping from ROS are always the chosen by almost everyone to make this task.

**Edit**

Thanks to @gvdhoorn now I know other implementation for ROS like [frontier_exploration](http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration) package and [turtlebot_exploration_3d](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_exploration_3d)

Which other implementations exists to use SLAM in the way I'm looking for?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270227/how-to-make-slam-with-other-programs-and-tools?/) by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-09-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-05**:
Is this related to #q269765 (your previous question)? If not, can you clarify what you actually want to do?

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-09-05**:
Oh, yes it is. I forgot I've asked the same question a week ago. In this case I should delete this question?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-05**:
We can close it as a *duplicate* and then optionally delete it.

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-09-05**:
Thanks for reopen this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [nav2d](http://wiki.ros.org/nav2d) package provides both SLAM and navigation for indoor robots. It can load exploration strategies to make the robot explore its environment autonomously. There are also [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/nav2d/Tutorials) how to set it up.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2017-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-09-06**:
Thanks a lot man, I'd like to use the package you've done. That's what I've been looking for. Just a few questions about the params: What about it performance for kinect? is it appropiate? I haven't found people who has used that sensor for it. And how it works for odometry?

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-09-06**:
I understand I need position (odom) and a vision sensor (kinect) which together as inputs are used for a filter like kalman or particle filter (this case). The thing is, I didn't see how can I send the odom info to this algorithm, can you tell me how to achieve that? Thanks

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2017-09-07**:
Odometry is input via topic tf, same as for navigation stack. I never used nav2d with a Kinect, which is a 3d sensor. But I think there are already ROS-nodes to create virtual 2d-scans from a Kinect sensor.

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-09-11**:
Thanks again man.